# Assign authority to a user without user input when updating user profile

Tags: grails, groovy, gsp

I've created a form that a user updates to update his profile. When I update the details of the user, and I log out and log in again, I get access denied. I found out that the reason for this was with the authority, every time I updated the table, other details were saved, but the authority is lost and as a result, access is denied.

So I would like to assign the role again within the form but without the user having any input. Any advise on how to implement that is appreciated.

below is my gsp;

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label  class="col-sm-5 control-label">
                                Roles
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-5 ">

                                <g:each in="${roles}" var="role" status="i">
                                    <div class="checkbox-inline">
                                        <g:checkBox name="roles" value="${role.id}"
                                                    checked="${role.authority == "ROLE_MEMBER" ? 'true': user.hasRole(role)}"/>
                                        <label for="roles[${i}]">${role.authority}</label>
                                    </div>
                                </g:each>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="${hasErrors(bean: user, field: 'natureOfIndividual', 'error')} required">
                                <label for="natureOfIndividual" class="col-sm-5 control-label">
                                    <g:message code="user.natureOfIndividual.label" default="Nature of Individual"/>
                                </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <g:select name="natureOfIndividual"
                                              from="${['Local', 'Foreign']}"
                                              class="form-control" noSelection="['': '-----Select-----']"
                                              value="${user?.natureOfIndividual}"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

With this code am not able to see the checkboxes. Still finding out why. But ultimately, I don't want the user to see any checkboxes, I want to assign the authority without his/her input.

I got a solution. In my UserController.groovy, there was updateRoles method that was called in update method. I commented out the method call. And now the roles are not affected after an update. Below is the code;

```
@Transactional
    def update(User user) {
        if (user == null) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            notFound()
            return
        }

        if (user.hasErrors()) {
            transactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()
            respond user.errors, view: 'edit'
            return
        }

        boolean passChange = false
        if (user.isDirty('password')) {
            passChange = true
        }


        user.save flush: true

        //updateRoles(user)
        request.withFormat {
            form multipartForm {
                if (passChange) {
                    flash.message = "A  user with username '${params.username}' and password '${params.password}' has been Updated"
                } else {
                    flash.message = "Your profile has been updated"
                }
                redirect user
            }
            '*' { respond user, [status: OK] }
        }
    }

    private updateRoles(User user) {
        UserRole.removeAll(user)

        List roleIds = params.roles instanceof String ? [params.roles] : params.roles
        roleIds?.each { roleId ->
            def role = Role.get(roleId)

            UserRole.create(user, role, true)
        }
    }
```

As you've seen, I have commented out the method call in the update method. So when users update their details, their authorization is still preserved.

Comment: remove the role-checkboxes from GSP and do the assignment in the controller

Comment: Do you have any resources I can follow to implement this??

Comment: Never mind, I've figured it out!! I'll Update my question